# How to override or disable launch agents in /System/Library/LaunchAgents?

Tags: macos, launchd

There's a longstanding and widely-reported issue with an Apple process (`photolibraryd`) that keeps creating a file called **Photos Library.photoslibrary** in the trash every few minutes. The process is launched as directed by `/System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.photolibraryd.plist`.

This directory is uneditable. I saw a comment in an Apple forum about copying a plist from there to `/Library/LaunchAgents` and editing it there, but there was no explanation as to why this would work. Does the system read this directory first and then disregard identically-named plists found under `/System`?

And if so, how can I specify a "dead end" or do-nothing action in the copied plist? I did try copying it there and specifying a nonexistent lib in its "program" element, but that had no effect.

I'm not really interested in app-specific workarounds to the photo-library problem. Using `fs_usage`, I caught this process hammering the trash folder hundreds or thousands of times a second with `getattr` and other status-checking commands. I have no need of any Photos-related functionality, and therefore I do not want this wasteful behavior to continue even if I can redirect it away from the trash.

On @Alexander 's suggestion I tried `launchctl`, but that resulted in:

```
sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PhotoLibraryServices.framework/Versions/A/Support/photolibraryd
Unload failed: 5: Input/output error
```

The terminal message then suggested using `launchctl bootout`. So I have now disabled SIP and done these:

`launchctl bootout gui/501/com.apple.photolibraryd`

`launchctl disable gui/501/com.apple.photolibraryd`

Aaaand now that I've restarted and run for a while, that didn't work either.